# error converting YAML to JSON, did not find expected key kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am doing a lab about kubernetes in google cloud.
I have create the YAML file, but when I am trying to deploy it a shell shows me this error:

```
error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 34: did not find expected key
```

YAML file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-config
        configMap:
          name: nginx-config
      - name: php-config
        configMap:
          name: php-config
      containers:
      - image: php-fpm:7.2
        name: php
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
        volumeMounts:
        - name: persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/www/data
        - name: php-config
          mountPath: /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
          subPath: www.conf
      - image: nginx:latest
        name: nginx
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/www/data
        - name: nginx-config
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
          subPath: nginx.conf
      volumes:
        - name: persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: nfs-pvc
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The overall file looks good.
There are some issues with indentation.

YAML file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-config
        configMap:
          name: nginx-config
      - name: php-config
        configMap:
          name: php-config
      containers:
      - image: php-fpm:7.2
        name: php
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
        volumeMounts:
        - name: persistent-storage
            # looks like indentation issue here                 
            mountPath: /var/www/data 
        - name: php-config
            # looks like indentation issue here                 
            mountPath: /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
            subPath: www.conf
      - image: nginx:latest
        name: nginx
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: persistent-storage
            mountPath: /var/www/data
        - name: nginx-config
            mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
            subPath: nginx.conf
      volumes:
        - name: persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: nfs-pvc
```

Comment: There I was thinking that indentation issues had been left behind with FORTRAN in the punched-card era.  If only people would come to their senses and use TABS not spaces! :)

Comment: Tabs are not allowed in YAML - "To maintain portability, tab characters must not be used in indentation, since different systems treat tabs differently. " See [spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html)

Comment: Had a similar issue. The issue was also caused by identation.

Answer (score 62):

yamllint package is useful to debug and find this kind of errors, just do `yamllint filename` and it will list the possible problems it finds. Install via your distro package manager (usually recommended if available) or via the below npm install command (it will install globally)

`npm install -g yaml-lint`

Thanks to Kyle VG for the npm command

Comment: For Ubuntu users `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yamllint -y`.

Comment: For Centos7 users, `sudo yum check-update && sudo yum install yamllint`

Comment: The Prettier vscode extension also validates.

Comment: For Mac users, `brew install yamllint` to install.

Answer (score 16):

Following `higuita`'s answer you can lint your yaml and check for errors without installing a module in your machine using [npx](https://github.com/npm/npx). I prefer this approach for commands that I do not intend to use often. NPX downloads the package, executes the command and remove the package when finishes.

```
npx yaml-lint yamllint file_name
```

Comment: For Ubuntu users `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yamllint -y`.

Answer (score 15):

I got that error while creating a yaml file for an `Ingress` using Helm. I had something like this as my Ingress specification

```
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - {{ .Values.ingress.host }}
```

and in the values.yaml

```
ingress:
  host: "[NAMESPACE]-example.com"
```

Turned out that the brackets where causing the error.

The issue could be fixed by putting quotes on the value using the `quote` function.

```
- {{ .Values.ingress.host | quote }}
```

This is also what the [Helm doc](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/values/#make-types-clear) recommends

> The easiest way to avoid type conversion errors is to be explicit about strings, and implicit about everything else. Or, in short, *quote all strings*.

and [here](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#quote-strings-dont-quote-integers)

> When you are working with string data, you are always safer quoting the strings than leaving them as bare words:

Answer (score 4):

Use a yaml parser to find the source of the problem

There is many online ones, like https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

Although the above yaml file looked fine, the indentation was the issue(which is hardly visible when looking at the file). Another issue that could cause this error, is having a problem with the file, such as a missing field name, or collon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I solve copying the link of the RAW Github file and set it on kubectl

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/project/master/file.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you don't have any invisible characters which are causing you issue.

This error:

```
error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 96: could not find expected '':''
```

Was because of an invisible break between the **: and the C** in this line:

```
- name: CERT_ALIAS
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, because of missing `|-` in values.yaml

WRONG

```
myconf:
  application:
    properties:
      my.prop=1
```

RIGHT

```
myconf:
  application:
    properties: |-
      my.prop=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this same error when attempting to create a template yaml file for multiple cronjobs where the settings were stored in an array in a values.yaml file.

Here is an example of the values data based on my actual code:

```
allCronJobs:
  - cron1:
    cronJobName: hello-world
    enabled: true
    cronJob:
      schedule: "2 * * * *"
    job:
      backoffLimit: 3
    pod:
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
  - cron2:
    cronJobName: foo-bar
    enabled: true
    cronJob:
      schedule: "0 11 * * *"
    job:
      activeDeadlineSeconds: 10800
    pod:
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Here is a snippet from the template file using the
range syntax. (This is the code that resulted in the error converting YAML to JSON)

```
{{ range $index, $currCron := .Values.allCronJobs -}}
{{- if $currCron.enabled -}}
{{- with $ }}
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: {{ include "api-payments.fullname" . }}-{{ $currCron.cronJobName }}
  labels:
    {{- include "api-payments.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  schedule: {{ $currCron.cronJob.schedule | quote }}
  startingDeadlineSeconds: {{ $currCron.cronJob.startingDeadlineSeconds }}
```

Thankfully, after much searching, I came across this post that helped me figure it out:  https://dev.to/ujwaldhakal/manage-multiple-cron-with-helm-flow-control-32i7

I needed to include "---" between each iteration of cronjob, just like helm does when processing multiple files (which are usually a single resource per file).

Here is the corrected code that now works.  The change is on line 4.

```
{{ range $index, $currCron := .Values.allCronJobs -}}
{{- if $currCron.enabled -}}
{{- with $ }}
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: {{ include "api-payments.fullname" . }}-{{ $currCron.cronJobName }}
  labels:
    {{- include "api-payments.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  schedule: {{ $currCron.cronJob.schedule | quote }}
  startingDeadlineSeconds: {{ $currCron.cronJob.startingDeadlineSeconds }}
```