# Message "error: error parsing mongodb-deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 27: did not find expected key"

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I am doing a lab about Kubernetes. I have created the YAML file, but when I am trying to deploy it in a shell, it shows me this error:

> error: error parsing mongodb-deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 27: did not find expected key

This is the YAML file for MongoDB for Kubernetes:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: mongodb-deployment
 labels:
   app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: mongodb
   template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         app: mongodb
     spec:
       containers:
       - name: mongodb
         image: mongo
         ports:
         - containerPort: 27017
         env:
         - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
           valueFROM:
             secretKeyRef:
                name: mongodb-secret
                key: mongo-root-username
         - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
           valueFROM:
             secretKeyRef:
                name: mongodb-secret
                key: mongo-root-password
```

Comment: Which line is line 27?  `valueFrom:` should be camel-cased with only one capital letter, if that's your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error converting YAML to JSON, did not find expected key kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54479397/error-converting-yaml-to-json-did-not-find-expected-key-kubernetes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`valueFROM` is changed to `valueFrom`. Also, `template` was under `selector`, so I moved `template` out of `selector`, so it would be under `spec`.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: mongodb-deployment
 labels:
   app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: mongodb
  template:  #this and all the following lines are moved 2 places left.
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        env:
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-username
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-password
```